# how to add multiple themes to bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to add multiple color themes to bootstrap, how do I do that?

```
- bootstrap.min.css  
- red.css is the red variant
- blue.css is the blue variant
```

With scss I (so far) can make red.css and blue.css, but both have the full bootstrap.min.css in it. That's not the right way to do it. I've read many tutorials, but all tell me how to create your own theme, but not how to add several color themes to one bootstrap set up.